# Periodic data doesn't seem periodic when plotted as a surface

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, visualization, surface

I am simulating a problem where a wave is incident upon a multi-layered sphere.

I have a variable named `forceZ1` which is a function of two other variables named `phase` and `frequency`. I have solved an equation and found the matrix for `forceZ1`. Also I know that `frequency` is a 1*3000 matrix and `phase` is the same size. So obviously `forceZ1` will be 3000*3000.

In this case the phase is changing between `0` and `2*pi` and based on the data, I got that the force should be periodic with a period of 2π. This can be verified by plotting any column vector in `forceZ1` with respect to the angle, e.g.

```
figure(); plot(ang1, forceZ1(:,567));
```

Which gives:

[image: Example periodic output]

I tried to draw a surface `forceZ1` vs. `frequency` and `phase` but the figure does not show the periodic behavior. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Figure not showing periodic behavior]

Here's my plotting code:

```
Z=forceZ1;
X=ang1;
Y=frequency;

figure
surf(X,Y,Z,'edgecolor','none')
shading interp
view(3)
xlim([0,2*pi]);
xlabel('X=phase')
ylabel('Y=nondimensional frequency')
zlabel('Z=force in Z direction')
title('Force-Frequency-Phase')
colormap jet
```

I uploaded a [`.mat` file of my data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kuYETUVjQPQNSJah9ldHp2fwPZG_jhBk) for your reference.

Comment: @Niladri Thank you :)

Comment: There's insufficient information to solve this problem. Firstly, we can't tell if you're solving/evaluating the equations correctly; secondly, we don't know if you're interpreting your results correctly; and thirdly, we can't tell if it's something that can even be resolved by different plotting (perhaps the periodic behavior is multiplied by some damping exponent so it seems like it's not periodic). If possible - please add the code that creates the data you're plotting, if not - please upload this data as mat files to dropbox etc. Showing the equations you're solving can also help here.

Comment: @Dev-iL okay I did it , now can you help me?

Comment: Ok, I see your data now (there are many variables there..!). When you say "I have printed the data in MATLAB and it is proved" could you please provide the code for this? I'm trying to understand whether you're simply plotting some wrong thing.

Comment: There is information lacking about the sicence. Something is periodic if it repeats every 2*pi. Or 8723232*pi. Periodicity doesn't mean it repeats every pi, depends on the frequency no? It is likely that I am highly misunderstanding it, but there is no information here about why you thing things should be as you say they shoudl!

Comment: @Dev-iL First I have to explain this issue that this code is for a problem about an incident wave hitting a multi-layer sphere so clearly there should be lots of variables. Then I suggest you to just use variables named "forceZ1" , "frequency" and "ang1" where ang1 is phase. about being harmonic I refer you to this code for instance: plot(ang1,forceZ1(:,567)) which shows the change of force in its 567th frequency in terms of phase. Also I change my question to this statement that the force should be something except the figure I have plotted. which means I ask you to draw a surface for me plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `forceZ1` matrix got transposed somewhere along the way. The data is indeed periodic, as you said, but the direction of the periodicity is your **Y** axis.

It will start making sense if you plot your data like this:

```
surf(X,Y,Z.','edgecolor','none');
```

... leading to:

[image: Desired result...]

However, since your data contains harmonics differing by phase, magnitude and offset, you might want to try using a different type of chart that would accentuate the shapes of the harmonics, such as [`ribbon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ribbon.html):

```
figure(); ribbon(Z(1:40:end,1:100:end));
```

[image: Ribbon example]

... or try to make an animation, or an interactive chart using a slider for the shown frequency.

Also, it's possible that your data wasn't just transposed, but also flipped so you might need to use [`flip`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) to get the correct result.

Comment: I asked in question to plz draw this surface for me. Because I am do aware of this techniques you've shared. Thanks :)

Comment: @hossein.kh 1) I have provided the code to plot it as you wanted, but just didn't show the output - look at the first line of code in my answer. 2) A simple surface plot, in my opinion, is not the best way to visualize this sort of data, which is why I tried to give you an alternative that shows the periodic behavior in a much clearer way.